# how to find the strchr function in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

How I can use strchr function of C in c#.Pls give me some guidelines.....

Comment: Bookmark this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms123401.aspx - it's for the Microsoft Developer Network. All the documentation is there for all languages supported by MS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string.IndexOf` is the answer.

However, if you are looing for

**strchr function** `returns to the first occurrence of Character to be located in string, or NULL if c is not found`

you can do something as the below:

Create a function as

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Function: Strchr
        /// Returns the first occurrence of Character to be located 
        /// in string or null otherwise
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="originalString"></param>
        /// <param name="charToSearch"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private int? Strchr(string originalString,char charToSearch)
        {
            int? found = originalString.IndexOf(charToSearch);
            return found > -1 ? found : null;
        }
```

And call it as under:

```
string test = "hello";
int? res = Strchr(test, '3'); //Returns null
int? res = Strchr(test, 'h'); //Returns 0
```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 4):

`string.IndexOf`

Comment: @vishal_niist why not? what is different?

Comment: strchr function returns to the first occurrence of Character to be located in string, or NULL if c is not found....

Comment: @vishal_niist IndexOf returns -1 in this case. is it different?

Comment: @Andrey strchr gives you a pointer which you can then use as a new string for futher processing. this is extremely helpful with parsing. indexof gives you a number.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers do not seem to 100% understand the contract of strchr() and are not providing a true direct replacement ... it normally returns a pointer to a string starting at that character (NOT an index).

A "purer" implementation:

Warning: Not sure if this is as pure as possible as it probably gives a *new* string not pointer into original, like in C++.  May not be possible to get a true substr pointer.  But not a C# expert myself.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// C++ strchr Equivalent
    /// </summary>
    /// Let you fill out the stupid <param ...> tags.
    private string strchr(string originalString, char charToSearch)
    {
        int found = originalString.IndexOf(charToSearch);
        return found > -1 ? originalString.Substring(found) : null;
    }
```

But I also found this implementation even better b/c you can't simply do C++ ptr math of + 1 to the string to get past terminator ...

```
    /// <summary>
    /// C++ strchr Equivalent (with jump past character option)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="originalString"></param>
    /// <param name="charToSearch"></param>
    /// <param name="pastIt"></param>
    /// <returns>String starting at the search char</returns>
    private string strchr(string originalString, char charToSearch, bool pastIt)
    {
        int found = originalString.IndexOf(charToSearch);
        return found > -1 ? originalString.Substring(found + (pastIt ? 1 : 0)) : null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// C++ strchr Equivalent (Pure)
    /// </summary>
    private string strchr(string originalString, char charToSearch)
    {
        return strchr(originalString, charToSearch, false);
    }
```